# Apache C++ module persistent global objects

Tags: c++, apache

I want to keep some global objects in an Apache C++ module persistent across Apache child process invocations.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use some form of storage external to the Apache processes.

Basic choices:

- A database.
- Shared memory (OS dependent).
- Another process and use an IPC mechanism (eg. a socket)
- A file.

Which one is appropriate depends on your requirements, and you might combine them.  For example, "a database" is actually implemented as another process that makes things persistent in a file and it deals with concurrency issues in a known way.

In general, a database is probably the first thing to try and only go to other alternatives if you have specific issues that can be solved by taking a different approach.