# gsoap - define a variable to be persistent for all sessions

Tags: c++, gsoap

I'm writing simple webservice with apache/gSoap and C++.
According to my understanding normally the generated gSoap object gets initialized and destroyed per soap request.

What i want to achieve is to initialize a variable in code, so the variable will be persistent and could be re-used between all soap sessions.

lets say, i want to initialize a database connection (when apache webserver started), and then i could use the object in my soap methods without requires me to re-initialize each time in my webservice methods body. the database object then could be destroyed when the apache stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on a similar post: [Apache C++ module persistent global objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290706/apache-c-module-persistent-global-objects)

Basically you need some external storage. My advice is to use [Redis](https://redis.io/).